# Getting errors on Visual Studio 2015 Professional [ html-has-lang ]

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 Professional and trying to create a MVC project but the bugs and warning on the solutions keep coming up:

[image]

[image]

I manually add the `<html lang="en">` but still red lines there! How can I fix this?

Comment: This question needs an [mcve] to be answerable. Could you edit in the code that produced this? Perhaps there was more than one HTML file that triggered the linter.

Answer (score 1):

Try *Rebuild Solution*.

I was having the same issue, and this seems to do the trick.

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.